# Oracle SQL - most efficient way to implement is record read?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, oracle12c

We have a feature in our application where we query from a table all notifications that user needs to see. Basically, its kinda like how emails are shown in web sites. There is an icon in the upper right which shows an alert on how many new notifications you have, and when clicked it lists all notifications you have, segregating those read and unread notifications.

We query all notifications from a single table. The dilemma is how we implement marking records as unread or read. The initial plan is to have a flag for each record in indicate if read or unread. So we do the query, iterate the result set and set to the read flag to 'Y' for all those records that are 'N'. Performance wise it seems kinda wrong to iterate each record in result set and update the read flag. Is there a better way to do this? Is there  feature in oracle db to handle this? Handling this in front end is not an option

We are using Oracle 12c by the way

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is.  You use `update` to update the record or records that a user reads, identifying them using the primary key in the table being updated.

Comment: *"it seems kinda wrong"* is a feeing not evidence of a performance issue. Having said which, *"iterate"* suggests a suboptimal approach to using SQL, which is a set-based language. So, if you think you actually have a slow feature and you want some advice on improving it, please post the code (or an accurate facsimile of it) together with some metrics (and maybe an explain plan) which illustrate the problem.

Comment: *"Handling this in front end is not an option"*. This does undermine your analogy with email. With email a message is **unread** until I have read it or otherwise marked it as **read**.  It seems you're doing something different, and possibly something which might surprise your users.

Comment: FWIW: in messaging software, messages are usually not marked as "read" unless the user interacts with the message (e.g. in a separate page or popup). As a typical end user, I might expect that merely viewing a report of the message headers should not mark them as "read". The list page might have a checkbox next to each message, as well as "select all" and "mark all as read" options. /2c

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about performance, you should **not** loop over result sets if you can avoid it. SQL is a set based language so operate on sets, not records. Seriously, go read Stephen Feuerstein. You didn't give us any tables or anything, but you want to do something like:

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET read_flag = 'Y'
 WHERE read_flag = 'N'
   AND ...
```

This will update all the unread things to read at once. If you need to know how many were updated, Oracle has the `SQL%ROWCOUNT` you can look at right after this runs.

But also, don't worry about performance until you have to worry about performance. Don't assume this is going to be a performance problem with no proof. Honestly, for what I imagine this table would be like, marking a few rows as read is not going be a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like described here - https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause#collections

Modified example from link:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF t1.notification_text%TYPE;
  l_tab t_tab;
BEGIN
  UPDATE my_table
  SET is_read = 'Y'
  RETURNING notification_text BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab;

  -- Do stuff with the data in your collection. Return it or whatever.
END;
/
```